# Ingress nginx routing in kubernetes (convertign from docker-compose with nginx reverse proxy)

Tags: kubernetes, h2o, nginx-ingress

I'm trying to move from running some services in docker-compose to kubernetes, and struggling with the move from nginx reverse proxy to ingress nginx. The service uses [h2o ai](https://www.h2o.ai/products/h2o/) which has a web interface. I'm failing to bring up the web interface in the k8s version.

I think that I need to amend the spec in the ingress file to route appropriately, grateful for any pointers on how to do this.

In the docker solution with nginx as reverse proxy, when I access `http://k8s-master:3002` it redirects to `http://k8s-master:3002/flow/index.html` and displays correctly

For k8s,(I have the `ingress-nginx-controller` running as `NodePort` on `32000`) , I try to access `https://k8s-master:32000/h2otest` and get an error message as follows:

```
{"__meta":{"schema_version":3,"schema_name":"H2OErrorV3","schema_type":"H2OError"},"timestamp":1602674406013,"error_url":"Resource /h2otest","msg":"\n\nERROR MESSAGE:\n\nResource /h2otest not found\n\n","dev_msg":"\n\nERROR MESSAGE:\n\nResource /h2otest not found\n\n","http_status":404,"values":{},"exception_type":"water.exceptions.H2ONotFoundArgumentException","exception_msg":"\n\nERROR MESSAGE:\n\nResource /h2otest not found\n\n","stacktrace":["water.exceptions.H2ONotFoundArgumentException: Resource /h2otest not found","    water.api.RequestServer.response404(RequestServer.java:743)","    water.api.RequestServer.getResource(RequestServer.java:846)","    water.api.RequestServer.serve(RequestServer.java:465)","    water.api.RequestServer.doGeneric(RequestServer.java:301)","    water.api.RequestServer.doGet(RequestServer.java:225)","    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)","    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)","    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:865)","    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:535)","    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)","    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1317)","    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)","    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)","    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)","    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1219)","    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)","    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:126)","    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)","    water.webserver.jetty9.Jetty9ServerAdapter$LoginHandler.handle(Jetty9ServerAdapter.java:130)","    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:126)","    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)","    org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:531)","    org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:352)","    org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)","    org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:281)","    org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)","    org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)","    org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:762)","    org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:680)","    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)"]}
```

---

**UPDATE: based on Ken Chen's comment**

I've changed the ingress below to use `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2`

Now when I type `https://k8s-master:32000/h2otest` it redirects to: `https://k8s-master:32000/flow/index.html`

Typing `https://k8s-master:32000/h2otest/flow/index.html` directly works. **How do I amend the rule so that** `https://k8s-master:32000/h2otest` **goes directly to**  `https://k8s-master:32000/h2otest/flow/index.html` ?

---

The following contains the files for each version:

docker version

`docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
services :
  test-h2o-svc:
    build:
      context: h2o
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: test-h2o:3.30.1.1
    restart: always
    networks:
      - testnet
#    ports:
#      - 54323:54321

  test-reverse-proxy:
    image: nginx:alpine
    hostname: reverse-proxy
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3002:3002
    volumes:
      - "./nginx_files/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:rw"
      - "./nginx_files/sites-available/test.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/sites-available/test.conf:rw"
      - "./nginx_files/sites-available/test.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/sites-enabled/test.conf:rw"
    networks:
      - testnet

networks:
 testnet:
version: "3.5"
```

`nginx.conf`

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  4;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}



http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;
    keepalive_timeout  180;
    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/sites-enabled/*.conf;
    client_body_buffer_size     50M;
    client_max_body_size 2000M;
}
```

`test.conf`

```
upstream link_h2o-svc {
  server        test-h2o-svc:54321;
}

server {
  listen        3002;
  location / {
    proxy_pass  http://link_h2o-svc;
   }
}
```

`Dockerfile` for container: `test-h2o:3.30.1.1`

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

ARG H2O_VERSION=3.30.1.1

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install default-jdk unzip wget -y

RUN wget https://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-zeno/1/h2o-${H2O_VERSION}.zip \
    && unzip h2o-${H2O_VERSION}.zip

ENV H2O_VERSION ${H2O_VERSION}
CMD java -jar h2o-${H2O_VERSION}/h2o.jar
```

---

k8s version

```yaml
kind: Namespace
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: ns-test
  labels:
    name: ns-test
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: /snap/kompose/19/kompose-linux-amd64 convert
    kompose.version: 1.21.0 (992df58d8)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: test-h2o
  name: test-h2o
  namespace: ns-test
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test-h2o
  
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        kompose.cmd: /snap/kompose/19/kompose-linux-amd64 convert
        kompose.version: 1.21.0 (992df58d8)
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: test-h2o
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: test-h2o:3.30.1.1
        imagePullPolicy: ""
        name: test-h2o
        resources: {}
      restartPolicy: Always
      serviceAccountName: ""
      volumes: null
status: {}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: /snap/kompose/19/kompose-linux-amd64 convert
    kompose.version: 1.21.0 (992df58d8)
  creationTimestamp: null

  name: test-h2o-svc
  namespace: ns-test
spec:
  ports:
  - name: "54321"
    port: 54321
    targetPort: 54321
  selector:
    app: test-h2o
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  namespace: ns-test
  annotations:
    #ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
        - path: /h2otest(/|$)(.*)
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: test-h2o-svc
              port: 
                number: 54321
```

Comment: I have little knowledge of h2o but I think h2o requires some redirecting to some resources like `https://k8s-master:30439/h2otest/something` but your ingress is rewriting your target url to `https://k8s-master:30439/`. Check https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/#rewrite-target for more detailed rewrite-target tutorial.

Comment: This has helped me to move in the right direction, haven't quite solved. Have edited question with updated info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I amend the rule so that https://k8s-master:30439/h2otest goes directly to https://k8s-master:30439/h2otest/flow/index.html

That is not an nginx-ingress question. Like most of the other ingresses nginx-ingress is there to do name based virtual hosting and SNI (or SSL Name based virtual hosting) with SSL offloading. Out of the box it's limited in any more.

While nginx-ingress can do some basic re-writing, it's limited to rewriting `/path/(.*)` to `/(.*)` and passing it to the next container to handle the traffic from there. If you're wanting it to do more you're into writing config maps for nginx-ingress.
Yes you'll want to set annotations for client body size etc, but the app itself (not the ingress) needs to be handling the `/h2otest` -> `/h2otest/flow/index.html` rewriting (or `/` -> `/flow/index.html`).

From what you're describing your layout looks like
`(nginx)ingress` -> `app`

You may need to change the layout to `(nginx)ingress` -> `nginx` ->`app` with the middle nginx doing the `/` -> `/flow/index.html` rewrite

A word of advice. If you have any chance use name based virtual hosting rather than path virtual hosting (unless you have a good reason eg cors) for path based. Alot of apps these days just assume they are on `/` an the config gets "interesting" if you're elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

Nginx reverse proxy rewrite `/h2otest` to `/` but h2o redirect `/` to `/flow/index.html`. At this point, nginx does not have a rule to handle `/flow` so result to 404.

Try remove the path and use root `/` instead.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  namespace: ns-test
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            serviceName: test-h2o-svc
            servicePort: 54321
```

Comment: That works, but is it only possible to run this service at root? I have a number of other services that I wanted to put on their own subpaths e.g. `/h2otest`.  How could I run this service at a subpath?

Comment: That's more of an application configuration issue. Take kibana for example, it has an environment variable called `SERVER_BASEPATH` which is exactly for this case. Maybe h2o has similar setting?